# Sonar squid:S2095 when method return Connection

Tags: java, sonarqube, database-connection, sonarlint

Returning `Connection` using a method is a common practice,
For example in Hikari's [HikariConnectionProvider](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/d0cb0f8dab5e3edaea7c4d3c5807f006d3695880/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/hibernate/HikariConnectionProvider.java)

> ```
> public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
> ```

```
   {
      Connection conn = null;
      if (this.hds != null) {
         conn = this.hds.getConnection();
      }   
      return conn;
   }
```

But Sonar warns about closing connection

> Connections, streams, files, and other classes that implement the Closeable interface or its super-interface, AutoCloseable, needs to be closed after use. Further, that close call must be made in a finally block otherwise an exception could keep the call from being made.

I want to return a Connection I can use later, so I can't close it in those methods

How/if can I avoid such warning on main method to return valid connection?

**EDIT**
Added a false positive bug in Sonar community: [S2095 report on method return Connection](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/s2095-report-on-method-return-connection/6608)

**EDIT 2** Issue isn’t reproducible on latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, SonarQube (and in this instance, the SonarJava analyzer) has no guarantee that the connection returned by this method will ultimately be closed - hence the issue.

If you are confident that your code base has all the required resource-cleaning code in place somewhere else, my suggestion here is to mark this particular issue as `Won't fix` in the SonarQube UI.

Comment: I can ignore this warning (e.g. using `//NOSONAR`), but if a method return `Connection` why sonar expect to close it

Comment: Because a `Connection` object is expensive and holds system resources, so if the code calling this method never closes it, the resources remain in use - and the analyzer can't possibly check all client code for calls to `#close`. However, I suggest that you raise this point at https://community.sonarsource.com/ - there is a potentially interesting discussion in whether factory methods which return the `Connection` object should be excluded from the scope of this rule.

Comment: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/s2095-report-on-method-return-connection/6608

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue while creating connection with mongodb. So, what I just made connection object `Autowired` as I was using spring.

In this way the life cycle of connection object was managed by spring and we don't have to close the connection explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the question is more about Sonar and its false positive warning, also issue isn’t reproducible on latest version